# How to use the results from one API call in another API call in a Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices

Looking for a suggestion to use the results from one API call in another API call in a Spring Boot
for example
Below is my sample Feign Client Class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/API/v1/Json", consumes ="application/json")
public interface ExternalClientApi {
@PostMapping
Intger openSession(@RequestParam Integer paramOne, @RequestParam Integer paramTwo);

@GetMapping
Integer getSessionInfo(@RequestParam Integer sesisonId); 
}
```

Here is another class

```
@FeignClient(name "ExternalClient" , configuration = "SomeClass.class",
url ="http://localhost:9080")
public interface ExternalClient extends ExternalClientApi {
}
```

My sample Controller Class is

```
@RestController
public class ClientController implements ExternalClient  {

@NonNull
private final ExternalClient   externalClient;

private Integer sessionId = null;

@Override
Integer openSession(Integer paramOne, Integer paramTwo) {
paramOne = 100;
paramTwo = 200;
sessionId  = externalClient.openSesion(paramOne,paramTwo);
return sessionId;

}    

@Override
Integer getSessionInfo(Integer sesionId) {
return externalClient.getSessionInfo(sessionId);
}

}
```

what is the best way to invoke getSessionIndo() API method from controller class above based on the result from openSession() API call ?

Comment: Do you mean call one HTTP route from another within the same app? Why would you involve HTTP for this?

Comment: second REST call is dependent on the first one so

Comment: Okay, but if you've properly designed your code, you'd have some Service class within the Controller. Once you get the request inside a controller method, you can use as many services as you want without going back out from the Controller to its other HTTP handlers

Comment: check to feign interceptor. Maybe you can use it in this.